# How can i start record my call using plivo?

Tags: java, plivo

When I enter any number in text box. I receive a call from plivo number and I get `request_uuid` and `call_uuid.Now`. I want to record the call.

When i make call to another person and he/she received my call it should be recorded.

Can anyone tell me how to complete this task?

```
package plivo.helper;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import com.plivo.helper.api.client.RestAPI;
import com.plivo.helper.exception.PlivoException;
import com.plivo.helper.api.response.response.Record;

public class RecordConference
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    RestAPI restAPI = new RestAPI("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "v1");
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> params = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("conference_name", "1234");
    Record response = new Record();

    try {
        response = restAPI.recordConference(params);
        System.out.println(response.url);
    } catch (PlivoException plivoException) {
        plivoException.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here i got `null` response as result.

Answer (score 1):

Hi try this for recording it works fine

```
public Class RecordConference {
  public static void main(String...args){
     PlivoClient newCall = new PlivoClient("v0.1", auth_id, auth_token , plivo_url, true);
     CallFeature call = newCall.call();
     Map<String, String> callParams = new HashMap<String, String> ();
     callParams.put("CallUUID", "eau76-rty-67ueg-876960-ghy");
     callParams.put("FileFormat", "wav");
     callParams.put("FilePath","/home/teleswitch/development/prompts/");
     callParams.put("FileName","record1");
     RecordStartResponse callResponse = call.recordStart(callParams);
     System.out.println(callResponse);
  }
}
```